# Navigation outside render function

Tags: react-native

I have a function to navigate to different component by checking in Async storage.

Here is my Loading Page Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
    View,
    Text
} from 'react-native';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export class LoadingScreen extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount(){
            async()=>{
                try{
                    const usertoken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
                    if(usertoken !== null ){
                        return this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
                    }else{
                        return this.props.navigation.navigate('Register');    
                    }
                }catch(error){
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')
                }
        };
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>This is loading...</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

But while running the app its not navigating to another Screen.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my register component:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text
} from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class RegisterScreen extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Register Screen</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
}

export default withNavigation(RegisterScreen);
```

Comment: Any warning or error?

Comment: No it just gets stuck in Loading Page.

Answer (score 0):

Export both `Login` and `Register` using `withNavigation`. Like below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Login </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default withNavigation(Login);
```

Comment: I exported the class withnavigation but this gives "The component for route ''Register" must be a React Component"

Comment: this will happen when the imported Component has not been properly exported. it looks like Register component is lacking an export. can you share the code of Register component ?